# What is my attack bonus and damage bonus with Shillelagh?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, damage, cantrips, attack-roll

The description of the *Shillelagh* cantrip says:

> The wood of a club or quarterstaff you are holding is imbued with
>   nature’s power. For the duration, you can use your spellcasting
>   ability instead of Strength for the attack and damage rolls of melee
>   attacks using that weapon, and the weapon's damage die becomes a d8.
>   The weapon also becomes magical, if it isn’t already. The spell ends
>   if you cast it again or if you let go of the weapon.

I have a quarterstaff (typically 1d6). My Strength modifier is -1, my proficiency bonus is +2, and my Wisdom modifier is +4.

With *Shillelagh*, does the damage roll become 1d8+4?

What does my attack bonus become? Is it still +1 (-1+2)? Or do I use my WIS bonus so my attack bonus becomes +6?

Comment: Related: [Do I get my proficiency bonus with Shillelagh?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/70450/do-i-get-my-proficiency-bonus-with-shillelagh)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Assuming that Wisdom is your spellcasting ability (which it is if you are a Druid or Nature Cleric, two of the three classes which could use this spell), then

> ... you can use your spellcasting ability instead of Strength for the attack and damage rolls of melee attacks using that weapon. -PHB p 275

This means in your case that the attack will get a bonus of +6, and the damage will be 1d8+4. You could chose to use your Strength instead of your Wisdom if you preferred, but it would only reduce your ability to strike and damage a target

Answer (score 5):

I think it's worth emphasizing that [*Shillelagh*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/shillelagh) allows the caster to use **their** spellcasting ability, what ever that might be. This spell is *not* tied to a Wisdom modifier.

Your attack bonus is **your** spell casting modifier + your proficiency bonus if you're proficient with the quarterstaff (in your case, that makes it +6).

Your damage bonus would add **your** spellcasting modifier to the d8 from the spell.

Granted, non-druids would still need to find a way to access this spell, but that's easily done with something like the [Warlock's *Pact of the Tome* Boon](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/phb/classes#Warlock).

Comment: @aaron9eee: thanks for adding that!